# make one static library from whole project with cmake

Tags: linux, cmake

c++-project, say, `foo` is maintained by the cmake.
One wants to  create one library `libfoo.a` (with all classes/methods/functions created at the whole source-tree) to make possible creating programs that could linked to the library with `-lfoo`.

ok, let's consider now a toy example, and the prolbem will be clear. Directory `foo` (root of the project) contains directories `a`, and `b`. Two `CmakeLists.txt` are created:

```
# a/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(A <a_sources>)
# b/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(B <b_sources>)
```

And one `CMakeLists.txt` for root directory:

```
add_subdirectory(a)
add_subdirectory(b)
add_library(foo <foo_sources>
target_link_libraries(foo A B)
```

That was a surprise for me: **after building libfoo.a contains only methods from foo_sources**, and `a_sources`,`b_sources` are excluded.
That is ok in the case when executables are built with the same project: while creating executables cmake "guesses" that `a` and `b` must be linked if it is linked to `foo`.
But in the case executable is created "outside" project to use library `foo` one must link with `-lfoo -la -lb`, now imagine a project with lots of subdirectories - how to deal with it? so question is "how to create one library, aggregating methods from whole project with means of cmake?"

Googling led me to relatively recently embedded (appeared in 2.8.8) `OBJECT library` opportunity. Nice example of using it is shown [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library). Now the problem above can be solved with that:

```
# a/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(A OBJECT <a_sources>)
# b/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(B OBJECT <b_sources>)
# foo/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(a)
add_subdirectory(b)
add_library(foo <foo_sources> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:B>)
```

problem seems to be solved, unfortunately, not quite.

if dependency chain is longer than 2, for example, `foo` depends on `A`, which depends on `B`, problem still remains.
That is because,

> Object libraries may contain only sources (and headers) that compile to object files.

and

> Object libraries cannot be imported, exported, installed, or linked.

(quotes are taken from the same [link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library#Restrictions))

I've tried several combinations of `target_link_library()`, `add_library(), add_library(... OBJECT ..)` trying to link `A` and `B` to `foo` without success (error during cmake-process.)

I must be loosing something simple, please help, thank you!
I am not sure is it important: project is maintained at the linux.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're getting tangled up in the term "depends on". If you're building a library named `foo` and it has two parts, `A` and `B`, it doesn't matter whether `A` depends on `B`; the library should contain both. The CMake code you've shown will build `foo` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I support answer @Pete Becker@ . But it should be said as well that those libraries a `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>` and `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:B>` actually not a libraries at all, but rather cmake internal list of object modules. There is no dependencies between compilation of object modules (except auto-generated sources) so they can be done in any order and in parallel.

I guess more correct term for your intention is gathering together several `TARGET_OBJECTS` under single object library. That's really bad that you can't write `add_library(B OBJECT b.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>)`. But you always can implement this by yourself:

```
add_library(A OBJECT a.cpp)
set(A_OBJECTS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>)

add_library(B OBJECT b.cpp)
set(B_OBJECTS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:B> ${A_OBJECTS})

add_library(foo ${B_OBJECTS})
```

I.e just create special variables `_OBJECTS` to use them whenever you want to include those object libraries in library, executable or as part of other object library with that `_OBJECTS` flavor.